# Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository

Tags: git, git-subtree, git-filter-branch

I have a [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) repository which contains a number of subdirectories. Now I have found that one of the subdirectories is unrelated to the other and should be detached to a separate repository.

How can I do this while keeping the history of the files within the subdirectory?

I guess I could make a clone and remove the unwanted parts of each clone, but I suppose this would give me the complete tree when checking out an older revision etc. This might be acceptable, but I would prefer to be able to pretend that the two repositories doesn't have a shared history.

Just to make it clear, I have the following structure:

```
XYZ/
    .git/
    XY1/
    ABC/
    XY2/
```

But I would like this instead:

```
XYZ/
    .git/
    XY1/
    XY2/
ABC/
    .git/
    ABC/
```

Comment: This is trivial now with `git filter-branch` see my answer below.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown is right. This is no longer difficult to do but it is difficult to find the right answer on Google because all the old answers dominate the results.

Comment: Use of `git filter-branch` is discouraged. See [warning in docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning).

Comment: Please use an alternative history filtering tool such as [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/).

Answer (score 1273, accepted):

**Update**: This process is so common, that the git team made it much simpler with a new tool, `git subtree`. See here: [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475)

---

You want to clone your repository and then use `git filter-branch` to mark everything but the subdirectory you want in your new repo to be garbage-collected.

1. To clone your local repository:

   ```
   git clone /XYZ /ABC
   ```

   (Note: the repository will be cloned using hard-links, but that is not a problem since the hard-linked files will not be modified in themselves - new ones will be created.)
2. Now, let us preserve the interesting branches which we want to rewrite as well, and then remove the origin to avoid pushing there and to make sure that old commits will not be referenced by the origin:

   ```
   cd /ABC
   for i in branch1 br2 br3; do git branch -t $i origin/$i; done
   git remote rm origin
   ```

   or for all remote branches:

   ```
   cd /ABC
   for i in $(git branch -r | sed "s/.*origin\///"); do git branch -t $i origin/$i; done
   git remote rm origin
   ```
3. Now you might want to also remove tags which have no relation with the subproject; you can also do that later, but you might need to prune your repo again. I did not do so and got a `WARNING: Ref 'refs/tags/v0.1' is unchanged` for all tags (since they were all unrelated to the subproject); additionally, after removing such tags more space will be reclaimed. Apparently `git filter-branch` should be able to rewrite other tags, but I could not verify this. If you want to remove all tags, use `git tag -l | xargs git tag -d`.
4. Then use filter-branch and reset to exclude the other files, so they can be pruned. Let's also add `--tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty` to remove empty commits and to rewrite tags (note that this will have to strip their signature):

   ```
   git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter ABC -- --all
   ```

   or alternatively, to only rewrite the HEAD branch and ignore tags and other branches:

   ```
   git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter ABC HEAD
   ```
5. Then delete the backup reflogs so the space can be truly reclaimed (although now the operation is destructive)

   ```
   git reset --hard
   git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
   git reflog expire --expire=now --all
   git gc --aggressive --prune=now
   ```

   and now you have a local git repository of the ABC sub-directory with all its history preserved.

Note: For most uses, `git filter-branch` should indeed have the added parameter `-- --all`. Yes that's really <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> `all`.  This needs to be the last parameters for the command. As Matli discovered, this keeps the project branches and tags included in the new repo.

Edit: various suggestions from comments below were incorporated to make sure, for instance, that the repository is actually shrunk (which was not always the case before).

Comment: Good point! That would apply to most people using git filter-branch this way. In my case, I was segregating a library which had its own series of release numbers in tags, so I didn't want the project tags in my new repo. I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: As of today, filter-branch is not supported on Windows. It looks like it is coming soon though. Check the msysgit discussion group (at google groups) for details.

Comment: Why do you need `--no-hardlinks`? Removing one hardlink won't affect the other file. Git objects are immutable too. Only if you'd change owner/file permissions you need `--no-hardlinks`.

Comment: git-filter-branch set_ident() calls `LANG=C LC_ALL=C sed ...` for maximum compatibility with non UTF-8 aware sed. Therefore, git-filter-branch dies on commits with UTF-8 characters in the author: or committer: fields (see `git show --pretty=raw <commit SHA1>`). A workaround, use a UTF-8 aware sed (e.g. GNU sed) and edit git-filter-branch: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sed -ne ...`

Comment: Also the not-yet-included 'git filter-branch --split-submodule' can be used to preserve consistent history. http://vi-server.org/vi/bin/git-extract-submodule.patch

Comment: I find that if the `/XYZ` repo is large, the `/ABC` repo won't be as small as desirable. To further shrink things: `git clone /ABC /ABC.small ; cd /ABC.small ; git repack -A -d ; git gc --prune=DATE` where `DATE` is `date +%Y-%m-%d`. For some reason if I don't `git clone` and work on the clone, nothing shrinks. :-/

Comment: And if you want to rewrite your tags to not reference the old structure, add `--tag-name-filter cat`

Comment: Like Paul, I did not want project tags in my new repo, so I did not use `-- --all`. I also ran `git remote rm origin`, and `git tag -l | xargs git tag -d` before the `git filter-branch` command. This shrunk my `.git` directory from 60M to ~300K. Note that I needed to run both of these commands to in order to get the size reduction.

Comment: The git man page recommends, instead of `rm -rf .git/refs/original/`, `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d`; I guess the latter is more robust if refs are not stored in the right place.
Moreover, I believe that 'git remote rm origin' is also needed to shrink the repo, otherwise the refs from origin will keep objects referenced. @jonp, I think that was the problem for you.
Finally, to also rewrite other branches, one must set them up manually with `git branch` after cloninng, `-- --all` and remove `HEAD` (which stops rewriting of other branches).

Comment: For many readers (including me), the answer by itself was quite imprecise. Therefore, I incorporated most of the suggestions from comments after testing them. In particular, I made sure that after following this procedure, the repository is actually shrunk (which was not the case for me and various other people). I hope that is OK.

Comment: To remove references in Windows you can use:
for /f %a IN ('git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/') DO git update-ref -d %a

Comment: I found git-subtree to be effective as well, and much simpler. Found via this related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1307969/72

Comment: On Windows, I first tried the steps from the powershell prompt, but step 5b failed. Then I re-tried all steps from the git bash, and everything worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: From the 5 or so similar questions, this is the most valuable answer for me together with this link: http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/

Comment: @Jarl has suggested to edit and remove the `--aggressive` option to gc *"as it makes the size of the repo explode: see also [link](http://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/the-woes-of-git-gc-aggressive-and-how-git-deltas-work/)"*

Comment: One important note is that if you have multiple branches being preserved in Step #2, then you'll have to run Step #4 and Step #5 through each one. Or at least thats what happened for me.

Comment: Does this not create ABC/ instead of ABC/ABC/?

Comment: So, I've probably used this answer 10 times now and I keep wanting to upvote it again. Tons of stuff on stackoverflow has been useful, but this answer is the *most* useful so far. I've even put it in evernote for super quick referencing. Thanks!

Comment: How to use this if you want to take 2 directories?

Comment: N.B. this leaves the new repo structured as /ABC/ABC, instead of just /ABC (though someone edited the question after the fact to say that was what was wanted)

Comment: @Paul - it should be noted that this approach fails if the `ABC` folder ever had a different name - in this case, the history stops at the point when it was renamed.

Comment: That didn't reclaim disk space for me, the .git folder must have a bunch of unused history still in there as the pruned folder is 10s of KB yet the .git is 1.5 GB! Any ideas?

Comment: After I used filter-branch, all of the files in that directory were removed.

Comment: Really useful this is. However, if /ABC used to be called /XY3 until 3 commits before HEAD, will the resulting ABC repository not only have these 3 commits?  At least this is what I have found.

Comment: These answers are a bit confusing... Are the five steps in this answer now N/A?  Is the "The Easy Way" answer below the right answer?  When I first saw this answer, I figured the 'Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository' link was to more in depth documentation and was summarized by the five steps that followed.  Can this be clarified?  Perhaps add a header above the five steps, like "The Old Way (pre v1.7.11).

Comment: Github wiki with the same steps https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Comment: Also, instead of cloning a repo in the first place, you can directly add a submodule which adds the new repo to git and creates the new repo into your current repo as well !

Comment: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo is the suggested way by git itself to easily do this.

Answer (score 1603):

## The Easy Way™

It turns out that this is such a common and useful practice that the overlords of Git made it really easy (added in version 1.7.11 - May 2012). Also, there's a **real-world example** in the **walkthrough** *below*.

0. Prepare the old repo

   ```
    cd <big-repo>
    git subtree split -P <name-of-folder> -b <name-of-new-branch>
   ```

   **Note:** `<name-of-folder>` must NOT contain leading or trailing characters.  For instance, the folder named `subproject` MUST be passed as `subproject`, NOT `./subproject/`

   **Note:** `<name-of-new-branch>` is a branch you will be creating in the existing/old repo, **NOT** the new one [that comes later].

   **Note for Windows users:** When your folder depth is > 1, `<name-of-folder>` must have *nix style folder separator (/). For instance, the folder named `path1\path2\subproject` MUST be passed as `path1/path2/subproject`
1. Create the new repo

   ```
    mkdir ~/<new-repo> && cd ~/<new-repo>
    git init
    git pull </path/to/big-repo> <name-of-new-branch>
   ```
2. Link the new repo to GitHub or wherever

   ```
    git remote add origin <git@github.com:user/new-repo.git>
    git push -u origin master
   ```
3. Cleanup inside `<big-repo>`, *if desired*

   ```
    git rm -rf <name-of-folder>
   ```

   **Note**: This leaves all the historical references in the repository. See the **Appendix** below if you're actually concerned about having committed a password or you need to decreasing the file size of your `.git` folder.

---

## Walkthrough

These are the **same steps as above**, but following my exact steps for my repository instead of using `<meta-named-things>`.

Here's a project I have for implementing JavaScript browser modules in node:

```
tree ~/node-browser-compat

node-browser-compat
├── ArrayBuffer
├── Audio
├── Blob
├── FormData
├── atob
├── btoa
├── location
└── navigator
```

I want to split out a single folder, `btoa`, into a separate Git repository

```
cd ~/node-browser-compat/
git subtree split -P btoa -b btoa-only
```

I now have a new branch, `btoa-only`, that only has commits for `btoa` and I want to create a new repository.

```
mkdir ~/btoa/ && cd ~/btoa/
git init
git pull ~/node-browser-compat btoa-only
```

Next, I create a new repo on GitHub or Bitbucket, or whatever and add it as the `origin`

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:node-browser-compat/btoa.git
git push -u origin master
```

Happy day!

**Note:** If you created a repo with a `README.md`, `.gitignore` and `LICENSE`, you will need to pull first:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

Lastly, I'll want to remove the folder from the bigger repo

```
git rm -rf btoa
```

---

### Clearing your history

By default, removing files from Git doesn't actually remove them; it just commits that they aren't there any more. If you want to actually remove the historical references (i.e. you committed a password), you need to do this:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter 'rm -rf <name-of-folder>' HEAD
```

After that, you can check that your file or folder no longer shows up in the Git history at all:

```
git log -- <name-of-folder> # should show nothing
```

However, you **can't "push" deletes to GitHub** and the like. If you try, you'll get an error and you'll have to `git pull` before you can `git push` - and then you're back to having everything in your history.

So if you want to delete history from the "origin" - meaning to delete it from GitHub, Bitbucket, etc - you'll need to delete the repo and re-push a pruned copy of the repo. But wait - **there's more**! - if you're really concerned about getting rid of a password or something like that you'll need to prune the backup (see below).

### Making `.git` smaller

The aforementioned delete history command still leaves behind a bunch of backup files - because Git is all too kind in helping you to not ruin your repo by accident. It will eventually delete orphaned files over the days and months, but it leaves them there for a while in case you realize that you accidentally deleted something you didn't want to.

So if you really want to *empty the trash* to **reduce the clone size** of a repo immediately you have to do all of this really weird stuff:

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && \
git reflog expire --all && \
git gc --aggressive --prune=now

git reflog expire --all --expire-unreachable=0
git repack -A -d
git prune
```

That said, I'd recommend not performing these steps unless you know that you need to - just in case you did prune the wrong subdirectory, y'know? The backup files shouldn't get cloned when you push the repo, they'll just be in your local copy.

## Credit

- http://psionides.eu/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/
- [Remove a directory permanently from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216733/remove-a-directory-permanently-from-git)
- http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/
- [How to remove unreferenced blobs from my Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo)

Comment: ...in particular, not on Ubuntu, even not when using `ppa:git-core/ppa` :-(

Comment: @rui.araujo: I ended up with creating a small shell script in my `~/bin` directory that sources `git-subtree.sh`: https://gist.github.com/6338779. Of course this has to be `chmod +x`-d, too,

Comment: If you have pushed a password to a public repository, you should change the password, not try to remove it from the public repo and hope nobody saw it.

Comment: You can override the push error when pushing to GitHub by doing `git push -f` to force the overwriting.

Comment: @rui.araujo your comment is very useful and makes the answer complete. It would be good if it was added to the actual answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I call `git pull </path/to/big-repo> <name-of-new-branch>`, I get an error: `Couldn't find remote ref <name-of-new-branch>`.

Comment: This really helped me with a lot of repositories, specially using svn2git and then splitting the repository into multiple Git repos... Look at github.com/marcellodesales/svnedge-* for examples.

Comment: according to https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html for `git filter-branch`, using `git rm` instead of `rm` is faster.

Comment: on ubuntu 13.10 you can find it in the specified location: `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh` (without having to use the ppa).

Comment: When cleaning up, shouldn't the **branch** created with `git subtree` be deleted as well?

Comment: What about if we have a subdirectory which was previously renamed? I tried this on a `<name-of-folder>` which at some point in time was renamed from `<another-name-of-folder>`. When I look at the history in `<new-repo>`, the initial commit is the one which renamed the folder - all of the history before that is erased from `<new-repo>`

Comment: re "latest git on OS X": there is no need to mess with brew or any other extra package manager because the XCode command line tools include Git. Available from Apple free of charge, installs/updates without any hassle.

Comment: this seems to make a new repo with the contents of `ABC/`, but the new repo doesn't contain the folder `ABC/` itself, as the question asked. How would you do this?

Comment: In the example it looks like it's just foo names to me. xyz, xyz1, xyz2, etc. Anyway `mkdir ABC/; git mv ./* ABC/`. I'm sure there's some way to give a prefix - maybe `git read-tree --prefix=spoon-knife/ -u spoon-knife/master`. See https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/.

Comment: To pull the split subtree into a folder: `git subtree add --prefix <new/folder/path> </path/to/big-repo> <name-of-new-branch>`

Comment: @Bluu I tried this on an empty repo and it didn't work. But I added my first commit and after that your solution worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this method in order to split **multiple sub folders** into a new git repository?

Comment: What I finally did to split multiple sub folders into a new project was in `1.` before the `subtree split`, move the sub folders I wanted into a unique sub-folder, rewriting history to keep it when pulling (step `2.`): `git filter-branch --tree-filter "mkdir <name-of-folder>; mv sub1 sub2 <name-of-folder>/" HEAD`

Comment: @AnthonyO. Could you elaborate on your method ? Or even write an answer ? I am stuck here and would upvote it for sure.

Comment: I finally used the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954485/extract-multiple-directories-using-git-filter-branch/19957874#19957874 it works well for me so far.

Comment: Hey @AnthonyO. I am trying something similar to what you wrote to move multiple sub-directories, but its failing for me. The error I get is `rename sub1 to folder/sub1: No such file or directory` and same for the second directory. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Jason & PierreHenry : I've written what I did in a separated answer. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31859803/535203

Comment: Hey @AnthonyO. I also asked a similar question here: [Splitting many subdirectories into a new, separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839189/splitting-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository) and got it to work. But thanks, I will try out your answer too.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to pass `--prune-empty` to `filter-branch` to remove the empty commits that happen due to removing the directory

Comment: As a corollary to this very useful answer - should anyone else use the subtree approach, be advised to manually split-out the .gitattributes file! I fell victim to this and got a CRLF/LF warning after adding a single ' ' to a file.

Comment: As far as I understand with this method (`git subtree`) you will loose both branches and tags. Using `git filter-branch`-method as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/359759/300632 it is possible to keep/rewrite branches and tags.

Comment: This solution doesn't preserve history.

Comment: If your objective is to link the new repository as a [`submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) of the original project, then you need [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1307969/2227298) (Usage §) of *"How to extract a git subdirectory **and make a submodule out of it**?"*.

Comment: If at some point in the past you ran `git subtree`, you may get a `fatal: bad object` error when running the command again. Avoid this by passing in the  `--ignore-joins` option.

Comment: This method turns out to be essentially useless -- if you follow it you lose ALL branches other than master, and all the history that may be in those branches.

Comment: See rogerdpack's answer if you ever did any directory renames/moves in your commits which you wish to preserve. The `filter-branch` and `subtree` methods will not keep truncate commits at directory renames.

Comment: The special directory path requirements highlight the big problem of git being internally inconsistent sometimes, which makes it that much more obtuse.

Comment: The `popd` and `pushd` command make this rather implicit and harder to grok what it intends to do ...

Comment: The `git subtree split` command is **much** slower than the `filter-branch` approach.

Comment: On CentOS 7, do `sudo yum install git-subtree` to get the `subtree` command.

Comment: what about if your initial repository has many branches? this solution just preserves the master branch

Comment: Using the git subtree approach describe here, is there a way to preserve existing branches (and tags)? Since the whole relevant history is kept, that should be about restoring a pointer to a given commit?

Comment: How would you keep the btoa folder in the new repository?

Comment: For those coming here in 2022: A very good (probably better) alternative to the answer provided here, based on `git filter-repo`, can be found further down in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/58983975#58983975

Comment: Could I be getting an issue because original subfolder was in a private repo and the new one is public?

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov No. `git` is completely unaware any settings on GitHub. The CLI program was created without any relation to the SaaS product.

Answer (score 140):

[Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359759/42473) creates a new repository containing /ABC, but does not remove /ABC from within /XYZ.  The following command will remove /ABC from within /XYZ:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf ABC" --prune-empty HEAD
```

Of course, test it in a 'clone --no-hardlinks' repository first, and follow it with the reset, gc and prune commands Paul lists.

Comment: make that 
`git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch ABC" --prune-empty HEAD`
and it will be **much** faster.
index-filter works on the index while tree-filter has to checkout and stage **everything for every commit**.

Comment: in some cases messing up the history of repository XYZ is overkill ... just a simple "rm -rf ABC; git rm -r ABC; git commit -m'extracted ABC into  its own repo'" would work better for most people.

Comment: You probably wish to use -f (force) on this command if you do it more than once, e.g., to remove two directories after they have been separated. Otherwise you will get "Cannot create a new backup."

Comment: If you're doing the `--index-filter` method, you may also want to make that `git rm -q -r -f`, so that each invocation won't print a line for each file it deletes.

Comment: I would suggest editing Paul's answer, only because Paul's is so thorough.

Answer (score 98):

I’ve found that in order to properly delete the old history from the new repository, you have to do a little more work after the `filter-branch` step.

1. Do the clone and the filter:

   ```
   git clone --no-hardlinks foo bar; cd bar
   git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter subdir/you/want
   ```
2. Remove every reference to the old history. “origin” was keeping track of your clone, and “original” is where filter-branch saves the old stuff:

   ```
   git remote rm origin
   git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
   git reflog expire --expire=now --all
   ```
3. Even now, your history might be stuck in a packfile that fsck won’t touch. Tear it to shreds, creating a new packfile and deleting the unused objects:

   ```
   git repack -ad
   ```

There is [an explanation of this](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commitdiff;h=d0268de6d755c72ff375ec95a0cc0dbd99dc31e2) in the [manual for filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository).

Comment: I think somethink like `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` is still missing, isn't it?

Comment: @Albert The repack command takes care of that, and there wouldn’t be any loose objects.

Comment: yeah, `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` reduced much of new repo

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks!

Comment: And after all this I'm still getting the same error that I was getting before.

fatal: packed object xxxxxx (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-yyyyyyyy.pack) is corrupt

Answer (score 56):

When running `git filter-branch` using a newer version of `git` (`2.22+` maybe?), it says to use this new tool [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo). This tool certainly simplified things for me.

### Filtering with filter-repo

Commands to create the `XYZ` repo from the original question:

```
# create local clone of original repo in directory XYZ
tmp $ git clone git@github.com:user/original.git XYZ

# switch to working in XYZ
tmp $ cd XYZ

# keep subdirectories XY1 and XY2 (dropping ABC)
XYZ $ git filter-repo --path XY1 --path XY2

# note: original remote origin was dropped
# (protecting against accidental pushes overwriting original repo data)

# XYZ $ ls -1
# XY1
# XY2

# XYZ $ git log --oneline
# last commit modifying ./XY1 or ./XY2
# first commit modifying ./XY1 or ./XY2

# point at new hosted, dedicated repo
XYZ $ git remote add origin git@github.com:user/XYZ.git

# push (and track) remote master
XYZ $ git push -u origin master
```

*assumptions:*
 * remote XYZ repo was new and empty before the push

### Filtering and moving

In my case, I also wanted to move a couple of directories for a more consistent structure. Initially, I ran that simple `filter-repo` command followed by `git mv dir-to-rename`, but I found I could get a slightly "better" history using the `--path-rename` option. Instead of seeing last modified `5 hours ago` on moved files in the new repo I now see `last year` (in the GitHub UI), which matches the modified times in the original repo.

Instead of...

```
git filter-repo --path XY1 --path XY2 --path inconsistent
git mv inconsistent XY3  # which updates last modification time
```

I ultimately ran...

```
git filter-repo --path XY1 --path XY2 --path inconsistent --path-rename inconsistent:XY3
```

Notes:

- I thought the [Git Rev News blog post](https://git.github.io/rev_news/2019/08/21/edition-54/#an-introduction-to-git-filter-repo--written-by-elijah-newren) explained well the reasoning behind creating yet another repo-filtering tool.
- I initially tried the path of creating a sub-directory matching the target repo name in the original repository and *then* filtering (using `git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter dir-matching-new-repo-name`). That command correctly converted that subdirectory to the root of the copied local repo, but it also resulted in a history of only the three commits it took to create the subdirectory. (I hadn't realized that `--path` could be specified multiple times; thereby, obviating the need to create a subdirectory in the source repo.) Since someone had committed to the source repo by the time I noticed that I'd failed to carry forward the history, I just used `git reset commit-before-subdir-move --hard` after the `clone` command, and added `--force` to the `filter-repo` command to get it to operate on the slightly modified local clone.

```sh
git clone ...
git reset HEAD~7 --hard      # roll back before mistake
git filter-repo ... --force  # tell filter-repo the alterations are expected
```

- I was stumped on the install since I was unaware of the extension pattern with `git`, but ultimately I cloned [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) and symlinked it to `$(git --exec-path)`:

```sh
ln -s ~/github/newren/git-filter-repo/git-filter-repo $(git --exec-path)
```

Comment: Using `git-filter-repo` should definitely be the preferred approach at this point. It’s much, much faster and safer than `git-filter-branch`, and safeguards against a lot of the gotchas one can run into when rewriting one’s git history. Hopefully this answer gets some more attention, since it’s the one to address `git-filter-repo`.

Comment: acutally I am currently trying to get things to work with git filter-repo but unfortunately after running it, I am missing files, which were added in a commit, containing a path that was removed by filter-repo. For example:
```Foo/
       Foo.cs
Bar/
      Bar.cs```
All were added in the same commit. I want to move Foo and Bar in separate repos. So I cloned my repo in a folder matching the new repo name and did ```git filter-repo -path Foo``` Foo get's removed too. I am talking about a much bigger repo and it is working for every other file but not if it's a constellation like this.

Comment: If files were previously moved/renamed, this will not automatically retain the history before the move/rename. However, if you include the original paths/filenames in the command, that history will not be removed. For example, `git filter-repo --path CurrentPathAfterRename --path OldPathBeforeRename`. `git filter-repo --analyze` produces a file renames.txt that can be helpful in determining these. Alternatively, you may find a [script like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832729/6388118) helpful.

Comment: to move the subdir content to the root folder and keep only subdir files and corresponding history: `git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter path/to/subdir`

Answer (score 40):

*Edit: Bash script added.*

The answers given here worked just partially for me; Lots of big files remained in the cache. What finally worked (after hours in #git on freenode):

```
git clone --no-hardlinks file:///SOURCE /tmp/blubb
cd blubb
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ./PATH_TO_EXTRACT  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git clone file:///tmp/blubb/ /tmp/blooh
cd /tmp/blooh
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git repack -ad
git gc --prune=now
```

With the previous solutions, the repository size was around 100 MB. This one brought it down to 1.7 MB. Maybe it helps somebody :)

---

The following bash script automates the task:

```
!/bin/bash

if (( $# < 3 ))
then
    echo "Usage:   $0 </path/to/repo/> <directory/to/extract/> <newName>"
    echo
    echo "Example: $0 /Projects/42.git first/answer/ firstAnswer"
    exit 1
fi


clone=/tmp/${3}Clone
newN=/tmp/${3}

git clone --no-hardlinks file://$1 ${clone}
cd ${clone}

git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter $2  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

git clone file://${clone} ${newN}
cd ${newN}

git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git repack -ad
git gc --prune=now
```

Answer (score 27):

This is no longer so complex you can just use the [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) command on a clone of you repo to cull the subdirectories you don't want and then push to the new remote.

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter <YOUR_SUBDIR_TO_KEEP> master
git push <MY_NEW_REMOTE_URL> -f .
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. YOUR_SUBDIR in the above example is the subdirectory that you want to KEEP, everything else will be removed

Comment: Updates based on you comment.

Comment: This does not answer the question. From the docs it says `The result will contain that directory (and only that) as its project root.` and indeed this is what you will get, i.e. the original project structure is not preserved.

Comment: @NicBright Can you illustrate your issue with XYZ and ABC as in the question, to show what's wrong?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown is it possible to reuse the cloned repo and not use a new repo, i.e. my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269602/after-using-git-filter-branch-subdirectory-filter-how-do-i-still-use-old-repo

Answer (score 19):

**Update**: The git-subtree module was so useful that the git team pulled it into core and made it `git subtree`. See here: [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475)

git-subtree may be useful for this

http://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt (deprecated)

http://psionides.jogger.pl/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/

Comment: git-subtree is now part of Git, although it's in the contrib tree, so not always installed by default. I know it is installed by the Homebrew git formula, but without its man page. apenwarr thus calls his version obsolete.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a small modification to [CoolAJ86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151312/coolaj86)'s ["The Easy Way™" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/535203) in order to split **multiple sub folders** (let's say `sub1`and `sub2`) into a new git repository.

## The Easy Way™ (multiple sub folders)

1. Prepare the old repo

   ```
   pushd <big-repo>
   git filter-branch --tree-filter "mkdir <name-of-folder>; mv <sub1> <sub2> <name-of-folder>/" HEAD
   git subtree split -P <name-of-folder> -b <name-of-new-branch>
   popd
   ```

   **Note:** `<name-of-folder>` must NOT contain leading or trailing characters.  For instance, the folder named `subproject` MUST be passed as `subproject`, NOT `./subproject/`

   **Note for windows users:** when your folder depth is > 1, `<name-of-folder>` must have *nix style folder separator (/). For instance, the folder named `path1\path2\subproject` MUST be passed as `path1/path2/subproject`. Moreover don't use `mv`command but `move`.

   **Final note:** the unique and big difference with the base answer is the second line of the script "`git filter-branch...`"
2. Create the new repo

   ```
   mkdir <new-repo>
   pushd <new-repo>

   git init
   git pull </path/to/big-repo> <name-of-new-branch>
   ```
3. Link the new repo to Github or wherever

   ```
   git remote add origin <git@github.com:my-user/new-repo.git>
   git push origin -u master
   ```
4. Cleanup, *if desired*

   ```
   popd # get out of <new-repo>
   pushd <big-repo>

   git rm -rf <name-of-folder>
   ```

   **Note**: This leaves all the historical references in the repository.See the **Appendix** in the original answer if you're actually concerned about having committed a password or you need to decreasing the file size of your `.git` folder.

Comment: This worked for me with slight modification.  Because my `sub1` and `sub2` folders didn't exist with the initial version, I had to modify my `--tree-filter` script as follows: `"mkdir <name-of-folder>; if [ -d sub1 ]; then mv <sub1> <name-of-folder>/; fi"`.  For the second `filter-branch` command I replaced <sub1> with <sub2>, omitted creation of <name-of-folder>, and included `-f` after `filter-branch` to override the warning of an existing backup.

Comment: This does not work if any of the subdirs have changed during the history in git. How can this be solved?

Comment: @nietras see rogerdpack's answer. Took me a while to find it after reading and absorbing all the info in these other answers.

Answer (score 13):

The original question wants XYZ/ABC/(*files) to become ABC/ABC/(*files). After implementing the accepted answer for my own code, I noticed that it actually changes XYZ/ABC/(*files) into ABC/(*files). The filter-branch man page even says,

> The result will contain that directory (and only that) *as its project root*."

In other words, it promotes the top-level folder "up" one level. That's an important distinction because, for example, in my history I had renamed a top-level folder. By promoting folders "up" one level, git loses continuity at the commit where I did the rename.

[image: I lost contiuity after filter-branch]

My answer to the question then is to make 2 copies of the repository and manually delete the folder(s) you want to keep in each. The man page backs me up with this:

> [...] avoid using [this command]  if a simple single commit would suffice to fix your problem

Comment: I like the style of that graph.  May I ask what tool you're using?

Comment: Tower for Mac. I really like it. It's almost worth switching to Mac for in itself.

Comment: Yep, though in my case, my subfoldered `targetdir` had been **renamed** at some point and `git filter-branch` simply called it a day, deleting all commits made prior to the rename!  Shocking, considering how adept Git is at tracking such things and even migration of individual content chunks!

Comment: Oh, also, if anyone finds themselves in the same boat, here's the command I used.  Don't forget that `git rm` takes multiple args, so there's no reason to run it for each file/folder:

`BYEBYE="dir/subdir2 dir2 file1 dir/file2"; git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -q -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch $BYEBYE" --prune-empty -- --all`

Answer (score 7):

To add to [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359759/42473), I found that to ultimately recover space, I have to push HEAD to a clean repository and that trims down the size of the .git/objects/pack directory.

i.e.

```
$ mkdir ...ABC.git
$ cd ...ABC.git
$ git init --bare
```

After the gc prune, also do:

```
$ git push ...ABC.git HEAD
```

Then you can do

```
$ git clone ...ABC.git
```

and the size of ABC/.git is reduced

Actually, some of the time consuming steps (e.g. git gc) aren't needed with the push to clean repository, i.e.:

```
$ git clone --no-hardlinks /XYZ /ABC
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ABC HEAD
$ git reset --hard
$ git push ...ABC.git HEAD
```

Answer (score 7):

It appears that most (all?) of the answers here rely on some form of `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` and its ilk.  This may work "most times" however for some cases, for instance the case of when you renamed the folder, ex:

```
 ABC/
    /move_this_dir # did some work here, then renamed it to

ABC/
    /move_this_dir_renamed
```

If you do a normal git filter style to extract "move_this_dir_renamed" you will lose file change history that occurred from back when it was initially "move_this_dir" ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797191/how-to-split-a-git-repository-while-preserving-subdirectories)).

It thus appears that the only way to really keep *all* change history (if yours is a case like this), is, in essence, to copy the repository (create a new repo, set that to be the origin), then nuke everything else and rename the subdirectory to the parent like this:

1. Clone the multi-module project locally
2. Branches - check what's there: `git branch -a`
3. Do a checkout to each branch to be included in the split to get a local copy on your workstation: `git checkout --track origin/branchABC`
4. Make a copy in a new directory: `cp -r oldmultimod simple`
5. Go into the new project copy: `cd simple`
6. Get rid of the other modules that aren't needed in this project:
7. `git rm otherModule1 other2 other3`
8. Now only the subdir of the target module remains
9. Get rid of the module subdir so that the module root becomes the new project root
10. `git mv moduleSubdir1/* .`
11. Delete the relic subdir: `rmdir moduleSubdir1`
12. Check changes at any  point: `git status`
13. Create the new git repo and copy its URL to point this project into it:
14. `git remote set-url origin http://mygithost:8080/git/our-splitted-module-repo`
15. Verify this is good: `git remote -v`
16. Push the changes up to the remote repo: `git push`
17. Go to the remote repo and check it's all there
18. Repeat it for any other branch needed: `git checkout branch2`

This follows [the github doc "Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository"](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) steps 6-11 to push the module to a new repo.

This will not save you any space in your .git folder, but it will preserve all your change history for those files even across renames.  And this may not be worth it if there isn't "a lot" of history lost, etc.  But at least you are guaranteed not to lose older commits!

Comment: Found the needle in the git haystack! Now I can keep **ALL** my commit history.

Answer (score 6):

Proper way now is the following:

`git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER_NAME [first_branch] [another_branch]`

GitHub now even have [small article](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) about such cases.

But be sure to clone your original repo to separate directory first (as it would delete all the files and other directories and you probable need to work with them).

So your algorithm should be:

1. clone your remote repo to another directory
2. using `git filter-branch` left only files under some subdirectory, push to new remote
3. create commit to remove this subdirectory from your original remote repo

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [GitHub's guide to splitting subfolders into a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/). The steps are similar to [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359759/3357935), but I found their instructions easier to understand.

I have modified the instructions so that they apply for a local repository, rather than one hosted on GitHub.

---

> #### [Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)
>
> 1. Open Git Bash.
> 2. Change the current working directory to the location where you want to create your new repository.
> 3. Clone the repository that contains the subfolder.
>
> ```bash
> git clone OLD-REPOSITORY-FOLDER NEW-REPOSITORY-FOLDER
> ```
>
> 4. Change the current working directory to your cloned repository.
>
> ```bash
> cd REPOSITORY-NAME
> ```
>
> 5. To filter out the subfolder from the rest of the files in the repository, run `git filter-branch`, supplying this information:
>
>    - `FOLDER-NAME`: The folder within your project that you'd like to create a separate repository from.
>
>      - Tip: Windows users should use `/` to delimit folders.
>    - `BRANCH-NAME`: The default branch for your current project, for example, `master` or `gh-pages`.
>
> ```bash
> git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME 
> # Filter the specified branch in your directory and remove empty commits
> Rewrite 48dc599c80e20527ed902928085e7861e6b3cbe6 (89/89)
> Ref 'refs/heads/BRANCH-NAME' was rewritten
> ```

Comment: Nice post, but I notice the first paragraph of the doc you linked says `If you create a new clone of the repository, you won't lose any of your Git history or changes when you split a folder into a separate repository.` Yet according to comments on all the answers here both `filter-branch` and the `subtree` script result in the loss of history wherever a subdirectory has been renamed. Is there anything that can be done to address this?

Comment: Found the solution for preserving all commits, including those preceding directory renames/moves - it's rogerdpack's answer to this very question.

Comment: The only problem is that I can't use the cloned repo any more

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly this problem but all the standard solutions based on git filter-branch were extremely slow. If you have a small repository then this may not be a problem, it was for me. I wrote another git filtering program based on libgit2 which as a first step creates branches for each filtering of the primary repository and then pushes these to clean repositories as the next step. On my repository (500Mb 100000 commits) the standard git filter-branch methods took days. My program takes minutes to do the same filtering.

It has the fabulous name of git_filter and lives here:

https://github.com/slobobaby/git_filter

on GitHub.

I hope it is useful to someone.

Answer (score 4):

Use this filter command to remove a subdirectory, while preserving your tags and branches:

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter \
"git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch DIR" --prune-empty \
--tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: what is cat here?

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, here is how using GitHub on a Windows machine. Let's say you have a cloned repo in residing in `C:\dir1`. The directory structure looks like this: `C:\dir1\dir2\dir3`. The `dir3` directory is the one I want to be a new separate repo.

**Github:**

1. Create your new repository: `MyTeam/mynewrepo`

**Bash Prompt:**

2. `$ cd c:/Dir1`
3. `$ git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter dir2/dir3 HEAD`
   Returned: `Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten` (fyi: dir2/dir3 is case sensitive.)
4. `$ git remote add some_name git@github.com:MyTeam/mynewrepo.git`
   `git remote add origin etc`. did not work, returned "`remote origin already exists`"
5. `$ git push --progress some_name master`

Answer (score 3):

As I [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository#comment24306261_10185428), I had to use the reverse solution (deleting all commits not touching my `dir/subdir/targetdir`) which seemed to work pretty well removing about 95% of the commits (as desired).  There are, however, two small issues remaining.

**FIRST**, `filter-branch` did a bang up job of removing commits which introduce or modify code but apparently, **merge commits** are beneath its station in the Gitiverse.

- **[Screenshot: Merge Madness!](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/a3d2bdfb-119e-4c06-bbe7-31caa1e7f33c/40bf20f0378670f9f3307e03119fbdfc)**

This is a cosmetic issue which I can probably live with *(he says...backing away slowly with eyes averted)*.

**SECOND** the few commits that remain are pretty much **ALL** duplicated!  I seem to have acquired a second, redundant timeline that spans just about the entire history of the project.  The interesting thing (which you can see from the picture below), is that my three local branches are not all on the same timeline (which is, certainly why it exists and isn't just garbage collected).

- **[Screnshot: Double-double, Git filter-branch style](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/f474a082-1aa6-4fc5-a2ea-3a8978cf7eb0/b5ef88551c266df9af3d8b86d5a7dd56)**

The only thing I can imagine is that one of the deleted commits was, perhaps, the single merge commit that `filter-branch` *actually did delete*, and that created the parallel timeline as each now-unmerged strand took its own copy of the commits. (*shrug* Where's my TARDiS?)  I'm pretty sure I can fix this issue, though I'd *really* love to understand how it happened.

In the case of crazy mergefest-O-RAMA, I'll likely be leaving that one alone since it has so firmly entrenched itself in my commit history—menacing at me whenever I come near—, it doesn't seem to be actually causing any non-cosmetic problems and because it is quite pretty in Tower.app.

Answer (score 3):

## The Easier Way

1. install [`git splits`](https://github.com/simpliwp/git-splits). I created it as a git extension, based on [jkeating's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6006679/3306354).
2. Split the directories into a local branch

      `#change into your repo's directory
      cd /path/to/repo
      #checkout the branch
      git checkout XYZ

      #split multiple directories into new branch XYZ
      git splits -b XYZ XY1 XY2`
3. Create an empty repo somewhere. We'll assume we've created an empty repo called `xyz` on GitHub that has path : `git@github.com:simpliwp/xyz.git`
4. Push to the new repo.

      `#add a new remote origin for the empty repo so we can push to the empty repo on GitHub
      git remote add origin_xyz git@github.com:simpliwp/xyz.git
      #push the branch to the empty repo's master branch
      git push origin_xyz XYZ:master`
5. Clone the newly created remote repo into a new local directory

      `#change current directory out of the old repo
      cd /path/to/where/you/want/the/new/local/repo
      #clone the remote repo you just pushed to 
      git clone  git@github.com:simpliwp/xyz.git`

Comment: An advantage of this method compared to "The Easy Way" is that the remote is already set up for the new repo, so you can immediately do a subtree add. In fact this way seems easier to me (even without `git splits`)

Comment: Props to AndrewD for posting this solution. I have forked his repo to make it work on OSX (https://github.com/ricardoespsanto/git-splits) if that's useful to anyone else

Answer (score 2):

You might need something like "git reflog expire --expire=now --all" before the garbage collection to actually clean the files out. git filter-branch just removes references in the history, but doesn't remove the reflog entries that hold the data. Of course, test this first.

My disk usage dropped dramatically in doing this, though my initial conditions were somewhat different. Perhaps --subdirectory-filter negates this need, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out git_split project at https://github.com/vangorra/git_split

Turn git directories into their very own repositories in their own location. No subtree funny business. This script will take an existing directory in your git repository and turn that directory into an independent repository of its own. Along the way, it will copy over the entire change history for the directory you provided.

```
./git_split.sh <src_repo> <src_branch> <relative_dir_path> <dest_repo>
        src_repo  - The source repo to pull from.
        src_branch - The branch of the source repo to pull from. (usually master)
        relative_dir_path   - Relative path of the directory in the source repo to split.
        dest_repo - The repo to push to.
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your gitconfig:

```
reduce-to-subfolder = !sh -c 'git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter cookbooks/unicorn HEAD && git reset --hard && git for-each-ref refs/original/ | cut -f 2 | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d && git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --aggressive --prune=now && git remote rm origin'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure git subtree is all fine and wonderful, but my subdirectories of git managed code that I wanted to move was all in eclipse.
So if you're using egit, it's painfully easy.
Take the project you want to move and team->disconnect it, and then team->share it to the new location. It will default to trying to use the old repo location, but you can uncheck the use-existing selection and pick the new place to move it.
All hail egit.

Comment: The "fine and wonderful" part of subtree is that your subdirectory's history comes along for the ride.  If you don't need the history, then your painfully easy method is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily try the https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

This worked for me. The issues i faced in the steps given above are

1. in this command `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME` 
   The `BRANCH-NAME` is **master**
2. if the last step fails when committing due to protection issue follow - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found quite straight forward solution, 
The idea is to copy repository and then just remove unnecessary part.
This is how it works:

1) Clone a repository you'd like to split

```
git clone git@git.thehost.io:testrepo/test.git
```

2) Move to git folder

```
cd test/
```

2) Remove unnecessary folders and commit it

```
rm -r ABC/
git add .
enter code here
git commit -m 'Remove ABC'
```

3) Remove unnecessary folder(s) form history with [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

```
cd ..
java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders "{ABC}" test
cd test/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

> for multiply folders you can use comma
>
> ```
> java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders "{ABC1,ABC2}" metric.git
> ```

4) Check that history doesn't contains the files/folders you just deleted

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete
```

5) Now you have clean repository without ABC,
so just push it into new origin

```
remote add origin git@github.com:username/new_repo
git push -u origin master
```

That's it. You can repeat the steps to get another repository,

just remove XY1,XY2 and rename XYZ -> ABC on step 3

Comment: Nearly perfect ... but you forgot "git filter-branch --prune-empty" to remove all old commits that are now empty. To do before push to origin master !

Comment: If you made the mistake and still want to "repush" after having removed old empty commit, perform : "git push -u origin master --force-with-lease"

Answer (score -1):

Found this wonderful article [Original reference](https://www.deployhq.com/git/faqs/detatch-subdirectory-git-submodule) easy to follow. Documenting it here in case if it get's inaccessible.

**1. Preparing the current repository**

```
$ cd path/to/repository
$ git subtree split -P my-folder -b my-folder
Created branch 'my-folder'
aecbdc3c8fe2932529658f5ed40d95c135352eff
```

*The name of the folder must be a relative path, starting from the root of the repository.*

**2. Creating the new repository**

```
$ cd my-folder
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/adamwest/Projects/learngit/shop/my-folder/.git/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 192c10b] initial commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file
```

*Here we just need to cd to the new folder, initialise the new repository, and commit any contents.*

**3.Add new remote repository and push**

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:robertlyall/my-folder.git
$ git push origin -u master
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 199 bytes | 199.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:robertlyall/my-folder.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

*We add the new repository remote from GitHub here, then push our first commit to it.*

**4. Remove folder from main repository and push**

```
$ cd ../
$ git rm -rf my-folder
rm 'my-folder/file'
$ git commit -m "Remove old folder"
[master 56aedbe] remove old folder
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 my-folder/file
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 217 bytes | 217.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To github.com:robertlyall/shop.git
   74dd8b3..56aedbe  master -> master
```

*Finally, we cd back to the rooot directory, remove the folder from our main repository, then commit and push the change.
Now, we have the folder in our main repository but linked to a completely separate repository that can be reused across multiple projects.*